# box-shadow pegar os quatro cantos da imagem

Tags: css

Alguém sabe me dizer como eu deixo o `box-shadow` na mesma tonalidade da direita e do topo na esquerda e em baixo? http://prntscr.com/j3lwl7

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper_login" class="fixed"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.fixed {
     position: fixed;
}
#wrapper_login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset -120px 120px 120px #000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do colega @hugocsl, tem um quarto parâmetro além do blur, que pode ser interessante para o seu caso. Ele diz o quanto a sombra vai "avançar" antes de começar a transição do borrão, definitivamente deixando sólida (ou com a transparência inicial) a cor até aquele ponto.

Para fins de comparação usei exatamente o mesmo código do colega, mas acrescentei o quarto parâmetro (exagerei um pouco para você ver a diferença), e diminui o blur um pouco:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url(http://placecage.com/510/380) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
}
.fixed {
     position: fixed;
}
#wrapper_login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 50px #000;
    /* ajustar aqui o avanço ---^      */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_login" class="fixed"></div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, esse quarto valor é conhecido como `spread-radius`

Comment: muito bom, isso mesmo que eu precisava

Answer (score 6):

O que acontece é que o dois primeiros valores do `Box-Shadown` representam os eixo `X` e `Y`

```
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color */
box-shadow: -120px 120px 120px #000;
```

Então como vc quer que a sombra cresça para dentro em todas as direções de forma igual, vc não deve deslocar os eixos horizontal e vertical `(-120px 120px)`, basta mante-los com o **`valor 0`**, e trabalhas só com o **Blur** que é o terceiro valor. `box-shadow: inset 0 0 120px #000`

**Veja abaixo como fica o seu código com `X` e `Y` no `0`**

```css
body {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url(http://placecage.com/510/380) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
}
.fixed {
     position: fixed;
}
#wrapper_login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 120px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_login" class="fixed"></div>
```

- Leia mais sobre a propriedade `Box-Shadown` aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow