# Blur que está atrapalhando o navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Já tentei usar o "z-index=1", mas não funcionou.
Tentei tirar a navbar da div first blur, só que quando eu clico no botão ela não fica com "blur", mas se eu deixo dentro fica com bordas pretas do lado, como se fosse uma sombra, já tentei várias coisas enfim... queria que a navbar ficasse com "blur" quando eu clicasse no botão "entrar", mas que não ficasse com essa borda preta.

Obs: Os códigos tanto da nav.css e do JANE1estilo.css são da mesma página, só que em arquivos css diferentes... por isso da erro ao executar.

```css
.firstBlur {
  margin:20px 20px 0;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* coloque blur em todos os elementos menos no elemento com a class .modal */
.firstBlur.modalBlur > *:not(.modal) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
}
/* remove a cor escurecida do fundo, se quiser que fique escurecido ajuste a opacidade para 0.5*/



.log{
  margin-top: -400px;
}
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  background-color: black;
}




/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.imgcontainer + div{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;

}


/* Imagem do logotipo, caso queira alterar a posição dela ou aplicar efeitos, etc... */

.logo {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  margin-left: -14px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative;


}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
}

span.psw {
  
  margin-left: : -5px;


}

/* The Modal (background) */


.container1-blur{
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
/* The Close Button (x) */


/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s

}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;

  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <Meta charset="UTF-8">
    <Meta name="description" content="Site educaciona para deficientes auditivos">
    <Meta name="keywords" content="deficientes, deficientes auditivos, educação, surdos, educação para surdos, educação para deficientes, site educacional, projeto aval, aval, auxilio para surdos, ajuda com surdos, escola surdos, escola deficientes, surdos e mudos">
    <Meta name="author" content="Vitor Hugo Minhaco Junior e João Vitor Galhardo">
  <Meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/JANE1estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
 <!-- Não remover esse style -->

<style>
.firstBlur {
  margin:20px 20px 0;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
}
/* coloque blur em todos os elementos menos no elemento com a class .modal */
.firstBlur.modalBlur > *:not(.modal) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
}
/* remove a cor escurecida do fundo, se quiser que fique escurecido ajuste a opacidade para 0.5*/
.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- TODA PROGRAMAÇÃO DEVE SER FEITA DENTRO DA DIV firstBlur!!!-->

    <div class="firstBlur">
    
    <div class="navbar-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link active-link">
      <a href="#">Home
      </a>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" href="#">Entrar</a>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle"
            aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Faça o login!</h5>
                        
                      
                         </div>


                    
                    <div class="modal-body">


                    <!-- Início do formulário -->

                        <form class="log">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
     
      <div class="logo">
      <img src="logotipo.png" alt="Avatar" class="logo">
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Nome</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" name="psw" required>
        
      <button type="submit" class="shadow-pop-tr"style="background-color:#008080">Entrar</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Lembrar de mim
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container1" style="background-color:#008080; height: 60px;">
     
      <span class="psw" style="margin-top:0px">Esqueceu a<a href="#"> senha?</a></span>
      </form>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div>
  

   <!-- Fim do formulário -->


                    
                    
              


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Animação para tornar o fundo embaçado -->

    <script>
        (function () {
            //Show Modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('.firstBlur').addClass('modalBlur');
            })
            //Remove modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('.firstBlur').removeClass('modalBlur');
            })
        })();
    </script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  </script>
</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

```js
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
 $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link');
 $(this).addClass('active-link');
});
```

```css
a {
 outline: none;
}

.navbar-container{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #009688;
 box-shadow: 0px -20px 5px 20px #333333;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: right;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block; 
 padding: 10px;
 transition: color 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li .underline {
 height: 3px;
 background-color: transparent;
 width: 0%;
 transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
 margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li.active-link .underline {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li:hover .underline {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-container ul li:hover a {

}

.navbar-container ul li:active a {
 transition: none;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}

.navbar-container ul li:active .underline {
 transition: none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}
```

Comment: Cara não deu para entender bem o que seria essa borda preta, eu pelo menos não entendi... tem como vc editar a pegunta e colocar uma imagem sinalizando onde é tal borda ?

Comment: Já coloquei, perdão. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu principal problema é com o `box-shadow` mesmo e não com o `blur()`, repare que na classe `.navbar-container` vc colocou um `box-shadow: 0px -20px 5px 20px #333333;` veja que ele tem no terceiro valor `5px`, esse `5px` representa esse "esfumaçado" tipo um *blur* mesmo que vc está vendo e não consegue tirar pq ele não está no filter `blur()` e sim no `box-shadow`, assim como o último valor que é  de `20px` e representa o quando o `box-shadow` deve ter de largura antes de começas a "esfumaça", isso que está criando a borda preta que vc não quer.

Leia mais sobre `box-shadow` aqui:[box-shadow pegar os quatro cantos da imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290388/box-shadow-pegar-os-quatro-cantos-da-imagem)

Veja que ajustando isso ele funciona perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código corrigido. Recomendo que vc faça uma revisão no seu HTML pois vc deixou algumas divs abertas, mas vou deixar isso pra vc resolver.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<Meta charset="UTF-8">
<Meta name="description" content="Site educaciona para deficientes auditivos">
<Meta name="keywords" content="deficientes, deficientes auditivos, educação, surdos, educação para surdos, educação para deficientes, site educacional, projeto aval, aval, auxilio para surdos, ajuda com surdos, escola surdos, escola deficientes, surdos e mudos">
<Meta name="author" content="Vitor Hugo Minhaco Junior e João Vitor Galhardo">
<Meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/JANE1estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->

<!-- Não remover esse style -->

<style>
    .firstBlur {
        margin: 20px 20px 0;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    /* coloque blur em todos os elementos menos no elemento com a class .modal */
    .firstBlur.modalBlur > *:not(.modal) {
        -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
        filter: blur(8px);
    }

    /* remove a cor escurecida do fundo, se quiser que fique escurecido ajuste a opacidade para 0.5*/
    .modal-backdrop.show {
        opacity: 0;
    }





    .log {
        margin-top: -400px;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        /* background-color: black; */
    }




    /* Full-width input fields */
    input[type=text],
    input[type=password] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }



    .imgcontainer + div {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Extra styles for the cancel button */
    .cancelbtn {
        width: auto;
        padding: 10px 18px;
        background-color: #f44336;
    }

    /* Center the image and position the close button */
    .imgcontainer {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
        position: relative;

    }


    /* Imagem do logotipo, caso queira alterar a posição dela ou aplicar efeitos, etc... */

    .logo {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
        margin-left: -14px;
        margin-top: 130px;
        position: relative;


    }

    img.avatar {
        width: 40%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .container {
        padding: 16px;
        color: black;
    }

    span.psw {

        margin-left: -5px;


    }

    /* The Modal (background) */



    /* The Close Button (x) */


    /* Add Zoom Animation */
    .animate {
        -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
        animation: animatezoom 0.6s
    }


    a {
        outline: none;
    }

    .navbar-container {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #009688;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #333333;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: color 0.5s;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li .underline {
        height: 3px;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 0%;
        transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
        margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li.active-link .underline {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:hover .underline {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:hover a {}

    .navbar-container ul li:active a {
        transition: none;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:active .underline {
        transition: none;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0)
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1)
        }
    }

    @keyframes animatezoom {
        from {
            transform: scale(0)
        }

        to {
            transform: scale(1)
        }
    }

    /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        span.psw {
            display: block;
            float: none;

        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: 100%;
        }

    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- TODA PROGRAMAÇÃO DEVE SER FEITA DENTRO DA DIV firstBlur!!!-->

    <div class="firstBlur">

        <div class="navbar-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link active-link">
                    <a href="#">Home
                    </a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Faça o login!</h5>


                    </div>



                    <div class="modal-body">


                        <!-- Início do formulário -->

                        <form class="log">
                            <div class="imgcontainer">

                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="logotipo.png" alt="Avatar" class="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="container">
                                <label for="uname"><b>Nome</b></label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="uname" required>

                                <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" name="psw" required>

                                <button type="submit" class="shadow-pop-tr" style="background-color:#008080">Entrar</button>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Lembrar de mim
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="container1" style="background-color:#008080; height: 60px;">

                                <span class="psw" style="margin-top:0px">Esqueceu a<a href="#"> senha?</a></span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Fim do formulário -->







    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Animação para tornar o fundo embaçado -->

    <script>
        (function() {
            //Show Modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $('.firstBlur').addClass('modalBlur');
            })
            //Remove modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $('.firstBlur').removeClass('modalBlur');
            })
        })();


        $('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
            $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link');
            $(this).addClass('active-link');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```